# CMake: link a specific .o inside a library to my target

Tags: cmake

It's failed my google-fu, so I'm asking here.

For a whack-a-doodle reason, I want to link a specific object inside a library to my target.

For example, I want to link `foo.o` within `bar.a` to `foobar.so`.

Is there some syntax in CMake that makes this possible?

edit:    Ok, a bit more of my problem.

We're making a modular signal processing system with various 'levels' of implementation:

- Python reference model
- C/C++ floating point
- C/C++ fixed point
- C/C++ DSP optimized version

A separate .a file gets made for each C/C++ implementation.   They all support a fixed point interface and a floating point interface, though they only implement one of the interfaces and do a translate/trampoline to the other.

In other words, the floating point implementation has a floating point implementation of the algorithm and a fixed point entry point that translates all the input to float before calling the float based API.

A DSP optimized implementation implements the fixed point entry points, and provides a float 'trampoline' to convert from float to fixed before calling the actual implementation.

All of this stuff is for allowing us to mix/match implementations so we can start with the ideal floating point model and piecemeal develop an optimized DSP version.  It all works dandy in a C/C++ project where you just link the desired implementation of the module and it 'just works'.

The kicker is our initial model is python and we want to be able to call into the C/C++ code from python with pybind11 bindings.

The link time of pybind11 shared objects is really slow and makes really big objects (even with the recommended settings i'm ending up with 3MB dlls) and we're going to have a lot of modules, so i'm looking for a way to cut down on the number of `.so` we make by combining the fixed and floating entry in the same `.so`. by saying something like:

module_pybind.so = module_fixed.a(fixed.o) + module_float.a(float.o)

and module_fixed.a(float.o) and module_float.a(fixed.o) don't get included because they're just trampoline functions.

I know, it's all a bit whacky and convoluted and I'm torturing things in ways that are way outside the norm, but I'm hoping this might work.

If not, I can play more tricks with trampolines and have a pybind specific entry point that's only there for the implemented model.

Comment: `.a` is an archive of `.o` files. What exactly do you mean by "link .o to .so"? Just compile it to a shared library..

Comment: @KamilCuk I added some more information.    I suspect it's not possible to do what I want (i'm not even sure GCC/LD has an option to specify this).

Comment: ... So? Create `module_pybind.so` from those two .a files. `.a` files is an group of `.o` files - there is no difference between them. Just `gcc -shared -o module_pybind.so module_fixed.a module_float.a`. If you really want, you can unpack the `.a` file into `.o` files and use them. Oooch I think I get it.

Comment: @kamilcuk   Sorry, it's a bit more subtle than that.   Both `.a` have the same entry points so I can't just link both .a files and have it work.  I need some way to ensure i get the right `.o` from the right '.a'.   Either unpacking as you suggest or some other trick.   thanks for the discussion, though.

Answer (score 2):

`.a` file is an archive of `.o` files. You can unpack the archive with `ar x library.a` command with proper dependencies with `add_custom_command` + `add_custom_target`. Then just `add_library(... SHARED the_unpacked_object.o)`.

Comment: This is as close as I'm going to get to my desire.   Thank you for this.